# Is this "crowd-sourcing" question appropriate here?

Tags: support, allowed-questions

In [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/717019/the-best-strategy-and-highest-possible-score-for-the-threes-game) on the game "Threes!" it was suggested that a statistical approach might be informative. So I've had an idea.

I'd like to test some strategies with a programme. I'll take as many as I can and just give them $N$ games each.

The data might give me some idea of which strategy is best.

First of all, I'll need to learn how to programme. (I want to do that anyway, so I might prod the [programmers](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/).) But then I'll need to choose my strategies judiciously, which means I'll need a large variety to pick from.

Hence the "crowd-sourcing" question, "Can you think of any strategies for the game "Threes!"?".

> Is this appropriate here?

I'd make it a Community Wiki question and suggest my own strategies for the experiment. (I won't accept an answer either, unless it's particularly exhaustive of all strategies.)

I think it'll be a few months before I put it out there anyway . . .

Comment: Aside: if you need to learn how to program, [Programmers.SE] is **not** a site for you. I can recommend [Codecademy](http://www.codecademy.com/). More to the point: your current question "What's the best strategy for the game?" already invites user input for strategies. You can put "empirically best of known strategies" to emphasize you are not asking for a proof. No need to create a new question. Also, I don't think you'll get *many viable strategies*, no matter how you ask. Throwing "can you think of any" in the title will not do you any good; it's just an invitation for VTC "too broad".